# Alterei um valor na base de dados e nao tenho backups

Tags: mysql

Boas eu alterei sem querer um valor na base de dados que é importante e não tenho backups. Há alguma coisa que eu possa fazer para recuperar?

Comment: Aqui tem uma [resposta](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/72760), mas em inglês.

Comment: Pelo que eu pesquisei, não tem como não.